# How to get all heading tags listed from website

Tags: javascript, html, web

I would like to list all headings and their content from the current url im and put it into nested list according their location

here is some code i tried, but cant figure out the nesting part like

```
window.onload = word;
function word () {

var h=["h1","h2","h3","h4","h5","h6"];
var headings = [];
for (var i =0; i<h.length ;i++)
{


    if (document.getElementsByTagName(h[i]))
{
    headings[i] = document.querySelector(h[i]).textContent;
  alert(headings[i] );

}
else

{ alert(h[i]+"doesn't exist");
    }

}

}
```

the nesting should look lik
-h1

-h2

--h3

---h4

-h2

-h2

Comment: `var h=["h1","h2","h3","h4","h5","h6"]; var headings = document.querySelectorAll(h.join(",")); console.log(headings);`

Comment: You need a recursive function that looks for the headers with higher numbers after it finds a header.

Comment: @epascarello That won't detect the nesting.

Comment: It will be in document order and assuming nesting is correct should be fine.

Comment: What does "nesting" mean? Are you trying to build an array of strings with the number of dashes before the h tag representing which h tag it is?

Comment: for example, it finds an h2 a below it is h3, h4 & another h2. so the h3 will be put 2dashes, the h3 3dahses and the last h2 will get one dash since its a higher heading than h2 & h3